# Cache Control Mechanisms

Tags: cache

I m trying to find the difference between a server configured with “cache-control max-age=0, must revalidate” and server with “cache-control: no-cache, no-store”.
So for the first, to my understanding, is not caching sensitive info at all since max age is 0 and client needs to revalidate each time for change. However some of my seniors mentioned that is still vulnerable!! I don’t see my scanner getting that flag though. So,

1. How do I confirm the vulnerability with any tests, if any?
2. What’s the difference between max-age 0 and no-cache? Seemingly they are same. Is the later more secured along with no-store?

Comment: Sensitive information exposure with caching.

Comment: To the user via cache. I am going through this https://tools.ietf.org/id/draft-ietf-httpbis-cache-01.html. What i am not able to grasp is difference between max-age=0 (which I have now) and no-cache/ no-store, which is apparently more secured to what I have now!

Comment: Thanks. I had thought about it about user experience but these seemingly same terms are confusing to me. With max age 0 currently too, cache is not being maintained! Does the performance worsens (for users sharing common machine) with no cache/ no store? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTP(S) caching is defined in RFC 7234; there is not currently any superseding document, so this is what you should refer to.

The `no-cache` response directive is a bit of a misnomer. It doesn't prohibit caching a document. It allows caching a document, but it is immediately considered stale and must be revalidated with the origin server before being used. You'll note that this is exactly the same semantics as `max-age=0, must-revalidate`. In both cases, the content is cached, and if the server sends a 304 response to a validation request, the cached document can be used.

To actually request a cache to not cache a document, you would use `no-store`. In this case it is not even strictly necessary to specify `no-cache` as the document would not be cached anyway! But this can be much slower than `no-cache` alone, as the document must be re-downloaded in its entirety every time the user accesses it.

Perhaps the fact that one of the `Cache-Control` directives you used as examples did not contain `no-store` is what your seniors were referring to, though calling this a "vulnerability" is severely overstating the matter, and whether it's a security (though again this is usually privacy) issue depends on the content you're serving.

In most contexts where you are sending user-specific information it is sufficient to set `Cache-Control: private` and allow the user's browser to cache the data, while shared caches will not cache it. I can't think of much that really needs to be `no-store`d, except perhaps private keys, nuclear launch codes, data that changes every 15 seconds, etc...